# MousePressEvent catches signal unnecessary- PyQt4

Tags: python, mouseevent, pyqt4, polygon, qgraphicsview

So I have a QraphicsScene with a QGraphicsPolygonItem , which I flag as movable. And I also override the MousePressEvent. My code snippet tll now.

```
def mousePressEvent(self , e):
    self.endx = e.x()
    self.endy = e.y()
    if self.sender == 1:
        self.LineChange(self.endx , self.endy)

#...

def CreateFun(self):
    poly = QtGui.QPolygonF([QtCore.QPointF(100 , 100) , QtCore.QPointF(100 , 200) , QtCore.QPointF(200 , 200)])
    self.polygon = QtGui.QGraphicsPolygonItem(poly)
    self.scene.addItem(self.polygon)
    self.polygon.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
```

However the polygon isn't moving . And when I comment out the MousePressEvent , it moves fine . My guess is that the MousePressEvent , catches it before the PolygonItem does.

And the above functions are from a class inherited from QtGui.QGraphicsView. Any suggestions?

Comment: It's hard to diagnose without a complete code.

Comment: This is my code till now . Id just like to make a user interface having a right angled triangle , which can be moved , and the angle can be edited. http://pastebin.com/m3SLcqKK @Avaris

Comment: Could you please check my code? @Avaris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call the base implementation for the `mousePressEvent`. `QGraphicsView` normally passes these clicks to other items that might use them. If you don't call the base implementation you're basically 'trapping' the click.

Modify your `mousePressEvent` as following:

```
def mousePressEvent(self , e):
    self.endx = e.x()
    self.endy = e.y()
    if self.sender == 1:
        self.LineChange(self.endx , self.endy)
    # let the base implementation do its thing
    super(Palette, self).mousePressEvent(e)
```

Comment: Thanks again. I also have one more question . Suppose I have a QPolygonF item , with 4 corners , that is passed to a QGraphicsPolygonItem , which in turn is set to a QGraohicsScene . I want to extend or basically rotate the polygon , according to where the user clicks , Ive been trying to find syntax but not able to . Any suggestions?

Comment: @Manoj: Rotation is easy. [`setRotation`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qgraphicsitem.html#setRotation) is all you need. Extending depends on what you want. Most straightforward way is calculating and re-setting the `QPolygonF`. Or you can make a `QTransform` and apply it with `setTransform`.

Comment: I guess Im confused with the syntax , Could you help to sort it out ,http://pastebin.com/ULy0aTVM

Comment: @Manoj: `QGraphicsPolygonItem` doesn't keep the original `QPolygonF`. So modifying the `polygon` won't affect your item. After changing the `QPolygonF`, set it again with `setPolygon` of your item. (e.g.: `poly.setPolygon(polygon)`)